# Javascript Random Number Generator comes up with NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

I am trying to make a random number generator using a form. When you press the button, and enter in the maximum number, it comes up with a dialog box reading NaN, when it is meant to come up with the random number.

I have some code that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<form name="gen">

<h1>Random Number Generator</h1>

<b>Number:</b> 1 to
<input id="numgen" type="text"/>               

<button name="generate" type="submit" onclick="gennum()">Generate!</button>

<script>
function gennum()
{
alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * num.value + 1));
}

var num = document.getElementById('numgen').value;
</script>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not very good with Javascript, but I know a bit. If anyone knows how to fix this, I would be happy.

Comment: `var num = document.getElementById('numgen');`

Comment: I'm just going to update my answer in a moment with a complete overhaul of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num.value` is a string. Use `parseInt(num.value, 10)` to turn it into a number, that way it can be added to a number appropriately.

Also, it looks like you're getting the value twice, and the first time is when the page loads (so it doesn't have a value yet:

```
var numElem = document.getElementById('numgen'); //remove value here
```

then in your function:

```
alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * parseInt(num.value + 1)));
```

and, you need to use `type="button"` on your button, or the page will reload.

### Here's your code refactored with better practices.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/uvUDovaY/1/edit)

**Markup:**

```
<form name="gen">
  <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>

  <b>Number:</b> 1 to
  <input id="numgen" type="text"/>               

  <button id="generate" type="button">Generate</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/* get element references */
var genButton = document.getElementById('generate');

var numInput = document.getElementById('numgen');

//use javascript to add the click function
genButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /* it's easier to read and debug if you break things up
   * instead of putting it all on one line with tons of ((()))
   */
  var rand = genRandom(1, parseInt(numInput.value, 10));
  alert(rand);
});

function genRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: And, properly, don't forget the radix: `parseInt(num.value, 10)`.

Comment: Thanks! I will remember those improvements next time I do some JavaScript.